# Query fails if select criteria is true on the first record-Cannot read property 'length' of undefined

Tags: custom-button, query

This should copy Opportunity Line Items to a Custom field when the product name does not include `"Discount"`. It runs perfectly when `"Discount"` is not the first line item. If it is, it fails with "Cannot read property `'length' of undefined"`

```
{!REQUIRESCRIPT("/soap/ajax/32.0/connection.js")}
{!REQUIRESCRIPT("/soap/ajax/32.0/apex.js")}
var record = new sforce.SObject("Opportunity");
record.Id = '{!Opportunity.Id}';

var retriveOpptyLineItems = sforce.connection.query("Select PricebookEntry.Product2.Name, Quantity, TotalPrice From OpportunityLineItem WHERE OpportunityId = '{!Opportunity.Id}' and (NOT Name like '%Discount%')");

var strProductNames = '';
for(var i=0; i<retriveOpptyLineItems.records.length ; i++){
strProductNames += 'PRODUCT NAME: ' + retriveOpptyLineItems.records[i].PricebookEntry.Product2.Name + ' --- QUANTITY: ' + retriveOpptyLineItems.records[i].Quantity + ' --- TOTAL PRICE: $ ' + retriveOpptyLineItems.records[i].TotalPrice +',' + '\n ';
}

sforce.connection.update([record]);
window.location.reload();
```

---

Here is the revised code. This results in the same error

```
{!REQUIRESCRIPT("/soap/ajax/32.0/connection.js")}
{!REQUIRESCRIPT("/soap/ajax/32.0/apex.js")}
var record = new sforce.SObject("Opportunity");
record.Id = '{!Opportunity.Id}';


var retriveOpptyLineItems = sforce.connection.query("Select PricebookEntry.Product2.Name, Quantity, TotalPrice From OpportunityLineItem WHERE OpportunityId = '{!Opportunity.Id}' and (NOT Name like '%Discount%')");


var records = retriveOpptyLineItems.getArray('records');
for(var i=0; i<records.length ; i++){
    strProductNames += 'PRODUCT NAME: ' + records[i].PricebookEntry.Product2.Name + ' --- QUANTITY: ' + records[i].Quantity + ' --- TOTAL PRICE: $ ' + records[i].TotalPrice +',' + '\n ';
}

var strProductNames = '';
for(var i=0; i<retriveOpptyLineItems.records.length ; i++){
strProductNames += 'PRODUCT NAME: ' + retriveOpptyLineItems.records[i].PricebookEntry.Product2.Name + ' --- QUANTITY: ' + retriveOpptyLineItems.records[i].Quantity + ' --- TOTAL PRICE: $ ' + retriveOpptyLineItems.records[i].TotalPrice +',' + '\n ';
}

sforce.connection.update([record]);
window.location.reload();
```

Here is the latest code.
It does not throw an error with "Discount" as the first line item but, the Line items dont get copied to the Samples_Sent__c field.
Opportunities without a "Discount" line item works fine

```
{!REQUIRESCRIPT("/soap/ajax/32.0/connection.js")}
{!REQUIRESCRIPT("/soap/ajax/32.0/apex.js")}
var record = new sforce.SObject("Opportunity");
record.Id = '{!Opportunity.Id}';


var retriveOpptyLineItems = sforce.connection.query("Select PricebookEntry.Product2.Name, Quantity, TotalPrice From OpportunityLineItem WHERE OpportunityId = '{!Opportunity.Id}' and (NOT Name like '%Discount%')");


var records = retriveOpptyLineItems.getArray('records');
var strProductNames = '';
for(var i=0; i<records.length ; i++){
    strProductNames += 'PRODUCT NAME: ' + records[i].PricebookEntry.Product2.Name + ' --- QUANTITY: ' + records[i].Quantity + ' --- TOTAL PRICE: $ ' + records[i].TotalPrice +',' + '\n ';
}

// var strProductNames = '';
// for(var i=0; i<retriveOpptyLineItems.records.length ; i++){
// strProductNames += 'PRODUCT NAME: ' + retriveOpptyLineItems.records[i].PricebookEntry.Product2.Name + ' --- QUANTITY: ' + retriveOpptyLineItems.records[i].Quantity + ' --- TOTAL PRICE: $ ' + retriveOpptyLineItems.records[i].TotalPrice +',' + '\n ';
// }

//eliminate the last ',' 
if(strProductNames.length>0){ 
strProductNames = strProductNames.substring(0,strProductNames.length-1); 
} 
record.Samples_Sent__c = strProductNames; 

sforce.connection.update([record]);
window.location.reload();
```

Comment: where it is failing? query is perfect

Comment: I'm not sure how to test for the failure point.  I tried pasting into Developer Console Open Execute Anonymous window and Execute Highlighted but that fails everytime

Comment: javascript and apex language are different, so this cannot be tested in Developer console

Comment: To debug this one, try catching the error from the query, replace line 6 with: `try{var retriveOpptyLineItems = sforce.connection.query("Select PricebookEntry.Product2.Name, Quantity, TotalPrice From OpportunityLineItem WHERE OpportunityId = '{!Opportunity.Id}' and (NOT Name like '%Discount%')");} catch(error){console.log(error);}`

Comment: oh.. ok. It only seems to fail if the first item on the list contains "Discount". If that item is anywhere else in the list it executes flawlessly. The error message is   Cannot read property 'length' of undefined.  Deleting the "Discount" item corrects the error.

Comment: The error message that says cannot read property 'length' of undefined is referring to the lack of `records` in your query results. You'll have to catch the error from the query to see why the query failed.

Comment: where will I find the error log?

Comment: You could switch `console.log(error);` to `alert(error);` so that it pops up. Otherwise it is web browser dependent.

Comment: THis does not popup an alert      try{var retriveOpptyLineItems = sforce.connection.query("Select PricebookEntry.Product2.Name, Quantity, TotalPrice From OpportunityLineItem WHERE OpportunityId = '{!Opportunity.Id}' and (NOT Name like '%Discount%')");} catch(error){alert(error);}

Comment: the code in my last comment produces the same error I've been getting.. Cannot read property 'length' of undefined

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you shouldn't loop through the raw result of the query but instead call `getArray('records')` on the object and loop through the resulting array to access the results.

```
var records = retriveOpptyLineItems.getArray('records');
for(var i=0; i<records.length ; i++){
    strProductNames += 'PRODUCT NAME: ' + records[i].PricebookEntry.Product2.Name + ' --- QUANTITY: ' + records[i].Quantity + ' --- TOTAL PRICE: $ ' + records[i].TotalPrice +',' + '\n ';
}
```

When the query returns at least one object, there is a "records" property

> {done:'true', queryLocator:null, records:{type:'Account', Id:'0019000001eBLgKAAW', },{type:'Account', Id:'0019000001jHBDaAAO', }, size:'2', }

When the query returns zero results, there is no "records" property

> {done:'true', queryLocator:null, size:'0', }

---

Have the new for loop replace the old one:

```
{!REQUIRESCRIPT("/soap/ajax/32.0/connection.js")}
{!REQUIRESCRIPT("/soap/ajax/32.0/apex.js")}
var record = new sforce.SObject("Opportunity");
record.Id = '{!Opportunity.Id}';


var retriveOpptyLineItems = sforce.connection.query("Select PricebookEntry.Product2.Name, Quantity, TotalPrice From OpportunityLineItem WHERE OpportunityId = '{!Opportunity.Id}' and (NOT Name like '%Discount%')");


var records = retriveOpptyLineItems.getArray('records');
var strProductNames = '';
for(var i=0; i<records.length ; i++){
    strProductNames += 'PRODUCT NAME: ' + records[i].PricebookEntry.Product2.Name + ' --- QUANTITY: ' + records[i].Quantity + ' --- TOTAL PRICE: $ ' + records[i].TotalPrice +',' + '\n ';
}

// var strProductNames = '';
// for(var i=0; i<retriveOpptyLineItems.records.length ; i++){
// strProductNames += 'PRODUCT NAME: ' + retriveOpptyLineItems.records[i].PricebookEntry.Product2.Name + ' --- QUANTITY: ' + retriveOpptyLineItems.records[i].Quantity + ' --- TOTAL PRICE: $ ' + retriveOpptyLineItems.records[i].TotalPrice +',' + '\n ';
// }

sforce.connection.update([record]);
window.location.reload();
```

Comment: I've posted my latest code. No error with "Discount" line item but Samples_Sent__c field does not get populated

Comment: I have a feeling that the update might be failing. What do you get when you replace the second to last line with this? `var saveresult = sforce.connection.update([record]);
alert(saveresult);` @Stavros

Comment: @Stavros If I had to guess, I'd say that the text string is too large for your field `Samples_Sent__c`. You might need to change it from regular text field to a long text area.

Comment: It already is a long text area (10,000) field

Comment: That sounds like a fairly generous amount of space. Were you able to see the result of the update call like I mentioned in the [comment before that](http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/136025/query-fails-if-select-criteria-is-true-on-the-first-record-cannot-read-property/136035?noredirect=1#comment-194306)? That might give us some insight on where the problem is.